# Replace null with a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know why my if statement doesn't do anything when running at the end of my program? I'm wanting to replace `null` returns with `no office` and I can't seem to run it afterwards.

[image]

```
for (z = 0; z < items.length; z++) {
  var team = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8"><p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].TeamName + '</p></div><div class="col-sm-4 office"><p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Office + '</p></div></div>';
  var single = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8"><p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Title + '</p></div><div class="col-sm-4"><p class="office" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">' + items[z].Office +
    '</p></div></div>';

  if (items[z].Office == 'null') {
    $(".office").append('No office');
  }
}
```

```
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
      <div class="row title">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <span>Single Users</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px;">
          <span>Office</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 teamsSingles" style="padding-left:0px; border-right: solid 1px #DCE1E5;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div>
      <div class="row title">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <span>Teams</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px;">
          <span>Office</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 teamsTeams" style="padding-left:0px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `'null'` is not same as `null`. One is a string other is an object representing no value

Comment: Is the value `'null'` (as a string) or `null`? Try just `if (!items[z].Office)`

Comment: Converting it to `null` instead of `'null'` worked - but now I'm just appending and not replacing - Didn't think about that, how do I go about that?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the quotes from around null (and add another = to check for type, so === instead of ==)

Comment: Answering a typographical mistake is a bad practice. A comment is more than enough for it

Comment: It's not typographical, the extra equals sign changes it so that it actually checks for type. Null is a different data type to 'null'. In the second case it is acually a string

Comment: Removed the single quotes and now i'm getting `nullNo officeNo officeNo office`.

Comment: Yes, so it's appending 'No office' if items[z].Office is null. So it's working

Comment: How would I go about replacing the null?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean? Replacing it in the check, or at its source (which may simply be an empty entry in a database or something)?

Comment: So if items[z].Office == null, replace the null in the .office class with "No office'. - There's no database, just html output.

Comment: So, a 16k rep. point user downvotes a 60 rep. point user because he misread the answer given by the new user, and it never gets fixed, by anyone! This site's user experience leaves a lot to be desired.